# How to calculate parenthesis

Tags: java, parentheses, polynomial-math

I want to calculate the `coefficients of x^i`(and the last number) resulted from calculating `(x+i1)*(x+i2)*....*(x+in)`, where `in` is integer.

Having for instance, `(x-1)(x-3)=x^2-4x+3`, I calculate the coefficients like this:

```
 x^2's is always 1
 x's is i1+i2 
and the last number is `i1*i2`
```

The problem comes when I have >2 parenthesis. I will get `(grade 2 poly)*( grade 1 poly)` and the algorithm that I described doesn't work, because there will be 3 coef. in the first parenthesis and my algorithm works only for 2. Basicly, I am looking for a generalization. What algorithm can I use, or is there any Java library or function to use?

Comment: You're going to have to parse a String that contains just integers, variables, operators, and parenthesis.

Comment: I'd like to not do that. Isn't there any way to calculate them directly like I did for i=2?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc how did you _calculate them directly_ without parsing? You need to work out what the order or the polynomial is and what all the variables `a` and `b` are in `(ax + b)` for each expression. Working out the [polynomial expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_expansion) after that is trivial.

Comment: I parse only the initial values i1....in from an array. I don't have the string (x+i1)*(x+i2)*....*(x+in), just the constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it after a few hours of hard work. Time to get a beer. Here is the code, feel free to use it.

```
private static int[] S_desfaparanteze(int[] poli) {

    int size = poli.length;

    List<Integer> rez = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> rezc = new ArrayList<>();

    // rez.add(1); adauga 1 in coada
    //rez.set(0, 2); pune 2 pe pozitia 0
    //rez.size() dimensiunea
    //rez.get(1) afiseaza elementul pe pozitia 1
    //pentru fiecare paranteza aka element al lui poli
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        //pas curent

        //adaug un 0 la sfarsit
        rez.add(0);

        //fac o copie a vectorului rezultat
        rezc = new ArrayList(rez);

        /*System.out.println("rez initial");
         for (int s : rez) {
         System.out.print(s + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("rezc initial");
         for (int s : rezc) {
         System.out.print(s + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();*/
        /*System.out.println("primul element: " + rez.get(0));
         System.out.println("primul element in copie: " + rezc.get(0));*/
        //primul element e calculat diferit
        rezc.set(0, rez.get(0) - poli[i]);

        /*System.out.println("rez dupa calcularea primului element");
         for (int s : rez) {
         System.out.print(s + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("rezc dupa calcularea primului element");
         for (int s : rezc) {
         System.out.print(s + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();*/
        //calculez si restul elementelor
        for (int j = 1; j < rez.size(); j++) {
            //System.out.println("pe" + j + "pun" + rez.get(j) + "+" + rez.get(j - 1) + "*" + (-poli[i]));
            rezc.set(j, rez.get(j) + rez.get(j - 1) * (-poli[i]));
        }

        //copii vectorul
        rez = rezc;

        /*System.out.println("la sfarsitul fiecarui pas, REZ");
         for (int s : rez) {
         System.out.print(s + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("---------------------");*/
    }
    /*System.out.println("la final");

     for (int s : rez) {
     System.out.print(s + " ");
     }*/
    //convertesc arraylist la array simplu
    int[] ret = new int[rez.size() + 1];
    for (int j = 0; j < rez.size(); j++) {
        ret[j + 1] = rez.get(j);
    }
    ret[0] = 1;
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this is to repeatedly multiply by each additional term.
assuming you have a `double[] coe` where `coe[j]` is the ij in your example and you have a term where in=nextTerm:

```
double[] multiply(double[] coe, double nextTerm){
    double[] product=Arrays.copyof(coe,coe.length+1);
    for(int i=0;i<coe.length;++i)
        product[i+1]+=nextTerm*coe[i]
    return product;
}
```

with some modifications this can be used for terms of the form ax+b.

Comment: Problem is (x+1)(x+2)(x+3) will become (grade 2 poly) * (grade 1 poly) like (x^2+3x+2)(x+3), so I have to treat old parenthesis different from a grade 1 poly.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc but I thought you had just the constants?

Comment: I do. But a grade 2 poly will have 3 constants(1,3,2 in my example). I don't want only the free number, I want all the coefficients of the resulting polynom.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc yes so the resulting double[] will take in the 3 constants of the degree 2 poly (1,3,2) and the constant of the next term (3) and give you back a degree 3 poly (1,6,11,6)